# How can I increase a counter based on a condition for a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of records, each labeled with a cluster value.

Original dataframe, **df**:

```
+-------------+---------+
| measurement | cluster |
+-------------+---------+
| M1          |       6 |
| M2          |       6 |
| M3          |       6 |
| M4          |      12 |
| M5          |      12 |
| M6          |      12 |
| M7          |       2 |
| M8          |       9 |
| M9          |       9 |
| M10         |       9 |
| M11         |       9 |
+-------------+---------+
```

How can I rename the clusters to a new number based on whether the current cluster value is equal to the prior and next one while assigning to "x" rows whose cluster values do not equal to the prior or next one?

Desired **df**:

```
+-------------+---------+-------------+
| measurement | cluster | new_cluster |
+-------------+---------+-------------+
| M1          |       6 |           1 |
| M2          |       6 |           1 |
| M3          |       6 |           1 |
| M4          |      12 |           2 |
| M5          |      12 |           2 |
| M6          |      12 |           2 |
| M7          |       2 |           x |
| M8          |       9 |           3 |
| M9          |       9 |           3 |
| M10         |       9 |           3 |
| M11         |       9 |           3 |
+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: according to your rule M1 should be x, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pandas.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) for filtered values by mask:

```
m = df['cluster'].ne(df['cluster'].shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'new_cluster'] =  pd.factorize(df.loc[m, 'cluster'])[0] + 1
print (df)
   measurement  cluster  new_cluster
0           M1        6          1.0
1           M2        6          1.0
2           M3        6          1.0
3           M4       12          2.0
4           M5       12          2.0
5           M6       12          2.0
6           M7        2          NaN
7           M8        9          3.0
8           M9        9          3.0
9          M10        9          3.0
10         M11        9          3.0
```

If want replace `NaN` to `x`:

```
df['new_cluster'] = df['new_cluster'].fillna('x')
print (df)
   measurement  cluster new_cluster
0           M1        6           1
1           M2        6           1
2           M3        6           1
3           M4       12           2
4           M5       12           2
5           M6       12           2
6           M7        2           x
7           M8        9           3
8           M9        9           3
9          M10        9           3
10         M11        9           3
```

Details for boolean mask - first create helper `Series` for consecutive values and then mask by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with keep='False' for return all dupes:

```
print (df['cluster'].ne(df['cluster'].shift()).cumsum())
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     2
6     3
7     4
8     4
9     4
10    4
Name: cluster, dtype: int32

print (m)
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
Name: cluster, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Oh my god...this is amazing. So concise and without a loop! Thank you jezrael!

Comment: This doesn't account for non-contiguous cluster values.  Meaning if cluster 2 appeared later in the data set it would be a duplicate but not equal to adjacent values.

Comment: side question, how did you load the data? using pd.read_clipboard?

Comment: @piRSquared - I agree, so added general solution

Comment: I'm happy now (-:

Comment: Ahhh right. piRSquared is right. I want to label the values that are not-contiguous as simply "x" even if their cluster values reappear later.

Answer (score 2):

### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    measurement=[f"M{i}" for i in range(1, 12)],
    cluster=[*map(int, '6 6 6 12 12 12 2 9 9 9 9'.split())]
))
```

---

### Solution

```
c = df.cluster.values
m0 = c[:-1] == c[1:]

# Test if equal to prior or next
mask = np.append(False, m0) | np.append(m0, False)

f, u = pd.factorize(c[mask])
new = np.array(list('x' * len(c)), dtype=object)
new[mask] = f + 1

df.assign(new_cluster=new)

   measurement  cluster new_cluster
0           M1        6           1
1           M2        6           1
2           M3        6           1
3           M4       12           2
4           M5       12           2
5           M6       12           2
6           M7        2           x
7           M8        9           3
8           M9        9           3
9          M10        9           3
10         M11        9           3
```